# Insensitive Sorting with comparator

Tags: java, string, sorting, comparator, collator

How can I sort Strings with String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, using collator or comparator? Actually, how can i combine them?

```
Comparator comparator=(Collator.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag(inputs.getLocale())));

Collections.sort(lines,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Comment: You want to sort collection of Strings disregarding capitalization like this: ALMOST, Always, another, bread, GREAT, zeus ?

Comment: it's something like ( a h m e t A H M E T -> A a E e H h M m T t)

Answer (score 0):

String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER is itself a static Comparator.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER

You can chain multiple comparators by using thenComparing
eg.

```
Comparator<String> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
             .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: Thank you, but I want to put the words to correct order in Turkish alphabet include ş,ç,ü,ö.